# Markdown/Hugo help: How to define a string to include bullet points?

Tags: markdown, hugo

I am trying to make a website using the [following template](https://themes.gohugo.io/aafu/). In `exampleSite/config.toml` I want to edit the following code:

```
[params.aboutme]
            title = "About Me"
            icon = "fas fa-user"
            description = "**Tagline. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet**, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."
```

I want to edit the description string such that the website will include bulletpoints where the description string usually goes. Do you know how I would do this? My naive attempt was to try this:

```
[params.aboutme]
                title = "About Me"
                icon = "fas fa-user"
                description = "My name is Peanutlex and I am interested in:
* Coding
* Football
"
```

However, this gives the error that strings cannot contain newlines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by adding another parameter (say skills) and define the items in an array:

`skills: ["coding","football"]`

Then, in your template:

```
<ul>

    {{ $skills := .Site.Params.Aboutme.Skills }}

    {{ range $k:= (seq 0 (sub (len $skills) 1)) }}

        <li>

            {{ index $skills $k }}
            
        </li>

    {{ end }}

</ul>
```